# JMeter while loop does not detect EOF

Tags: loops, csv, while-loop, jmeter, eof

I want to do "while" controller goes to the next controller when it reads EOF from CSV in JMeter. The while loop stops, but it iterates for 1 more time, I mean to say it does not need to iterate when it detects EOF. When I choose Stop thread on the EOF value as "True". The while loop stops and does not go for next loop.

I need to go to the next loop controller when the CSV file detects EOF without iterating one more loop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From this post on [BlazeMeter - Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter), I found you can combine a **While Controller** with an **If Controller** to get the desired result.

The condition to control the iterations in both the while and if controllers is the following.

`${__javaScript("${myVar}" != "<EOF>",)}`

**Note:** Make sure to substitute the variable `${myVar}`, with the variable from your csv file.

You need to use the **If Controller** to protect against an additional loop iteration because of when the while loop is actually evaluated.

All your samples are children of the **If Controller**.

The original post does a good job explaining it all.

Answer (score 3):

In your CSV config, change the setting of `Recycle on EOF?` to false.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSV config make changes to the following settings:-

1. Recycle on EOF = False
2. Stop thread on EOF = True